# Make any link (even _blank) open in same window using QWebEngine

Tags: python, hyperlink, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I have this code that is supposed to visit/follow any link that I click in the same window, even if it would normally open in a new window. This would be instead of having to right-click and then select "Follow link" from context menu. For some reason, it doesn't work as expected.

Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDesktopServices
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEnginePage


class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url,  _type, isMainFrame):
        if _type == QWebEnginePage.NavigationTypeLinkClicked:
            return True
        return QWebEnginePage.acceptNavigationRequest(self, url,  _type,      isMainFrame)

class HtmlView(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWebEngineView.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setPage(WebEnginePage(self))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = HtmlView()
    w.load(QUrl("https://yahoo.com"));
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want links to always open in the same window, you can reimplement the [createWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#createWindow) method, so that it returns the same view:

```
class HtmlView(QWebEngineView):
    def createWindow(self, wintype):
        return self
```

The `wintype` argument provides information about which type of window is being requested. You may want to treat dialog windows differently.

Note that the `WebEnginePage` subclass in your example is not needed for this to work.

Comment: It works but I have the webengineview in a centeral widget of a Qmainwindow so how I would make this work. I tried to return self.widget instead of self but didnt work.

Comment: @Maxwe11. You shouldn't change anything - it must be `return self`. There has to be a separate subclass of `QWebEngineView`, exactly as shown in my answer. Create an instance of `HtmlView` and set it as the central widget of the `QMainWindow`.

Comment: Done it but there is one more problem, When it createswindow the back history is not accessible anymore. is there any other way to do it? how i can just mimic the follow link in context menu of qwebengine?