# How to show a webpage in Qmainwindow?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have searched entire web to find a way to do this.

All the answers are about PyQt4, Pyside, Qwebview, Qt4, or Qt5(C++), therefore they do not work on PyQt5.

the other answer is `QtWebEngineView`: unknown for PyQt5 (at least mine).

I have the latest version of Python, Pycharm and PyQt5.

Comment: Some code snippets of what you have tried may be helpful to others that read your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In future I recommend you also tag the language you are using.  In this case `python` and  `pyqt5` together.  In order to find (and answer) your question users would need to be looking under the `pyqt5` tag.  Many who know `pyqt5` may not look under this tag specifically (so it is a good idea to maximize your audience while keeping it tagged with *all* relevant tags).  Also they will not know which language you are using and may for this reason skip it without reading.

Comment: Since you have installed PyQt5, and what is its version, you should have the QWebEngineView module, see this example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893838/make-any-link-even-blank-open-in-same-window-using-qwebengine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tnx All. The correct import was  `from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets`then, you can use `QWebEngineView`easily by `load()` method.